# ¿Por qué me sale este error en mi código (Python)?: puntos1 = (fun1(nom1, apellido)) NameError: name 'fun1' is not defined

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo este código pero me sale error al final. ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitarlo? Se supone que mi código debe de decir si el nombre que se escoge es compatible con el apellido. para ello están los siguientes criterios:
Ambos nombre y apellido tienen la misma cantidad de letras ---> 10 ptos
Ambos nombre y apellido empiezan con una vocal o ambos empiezan con una consonante ---> 5 ptos
Ambos nombre y apellido tienen el mismo número de vocales 10 ptos --->
Ambos nombre y apellido terminan con la exacta misma letra 20 ptos --->

Mientras más puntos se consigan, más compatible es el nombre.

```
nom1 = []
nom2 = []
nom3 = []
nom4 = []
nom5 = []
apellido = [] 

print('Ingrese los cinco nombres que le gustan para su bebé:')
nom1= input('1.' )
nom2= input('2.' )
nom3= input('3.' )
nom4= input('4.' )
nom5= input('5.' )
apellido = input('Ingrese el apellido del bebé:')

print ('---------menú-----------')
print ('1.', nom1, apellido)
print ('2.', nom2, apellido)
print ('3.', nom3, apellido)
print ('4.', nom4, apellido)
print ('5.', nom5, apellido)
print ('------------------------')

opcion = input('Escoja un nombre para calcular la compatibilidad:')

if opcion == 1:
    def fun1(nom1, apellido):
        if len(str(nom1)) == len(str(apellido)):
            return 10
        else:
            return 0

puntos1 = (fun1(nom1, apellido))
print(puntos1, 'puntos')
```

Comment: Porque la condición del `if` no se cumple, la función no se crea y de consecuencia te da un error diciéndote que no se puede ejecutar una función que no existe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función la estás definiendo dentro de una condicional, por lo que la función solo existe si seleccionan 1, de lo contrario no existirá.

Lo correcto sería hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
puntos1 = 0
def fun1(nom1, apellido):
        if len(str(nom1)) == len(str(apellido)):
            return 10
        else:
            return 0
if opcion == 1:
 puntos1 += fun1(nom1, apellido)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Igual habría un error no lo crees? Ya que lo del input es un string y en el ```if``` se compara con un entero lo cual haría que no se cumpla la condición, el resto esta bien

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha solucionado el problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada (pinchando el tick que tiene a su izquierda) esto ayudará a futuras personas con la misma duda.